# How to check the JSON response below for null array

Tags: java, android, json

This is my JSON response how can I check for the null array in android

```
[
 {
  "OrderDetails":[
     {
       "userName":"akhilm"
       "acc_name":"akhil001"
     }
    ],
  "OrderAttributes":null
  "OrderServices":[
     {
       "name":"aditi"
       "id":78934
     }
    ],
  "Message":null
  "Description":null
 }
]
```

The JSON data is dynamic

Comment: `Invalid JSON `

Comment: Using  `JSONObject.isNull(<ARRAY_KEY>)` ?

Comment: Y is it invalid JSON, the IOS team made the app already with this JSON

Comment: i am new to android, so i couldn't figure it out

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Thank you very much it worked

Comment: @AkhilMankala: If IOS team made the app, then they were did wrong development. First json should be valid then it will be used in app

Comment: JSON is correct, I got it with what @ρяσѕρєяK suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

    if(json.isNull("OrderAttributes")) {
        //TODO: it is null
    } else {
        //TODO: it is not null
        String orderAttributes = json.getString("OrderAttributes");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (json.has("key string")) {
    String status = json.getString("key string"));
 }
else {
 Log.e("status", "key value not present ")
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);        
    System.out.println(jsonObj .isNull("error") ? " error is null ":" error is not null" );
```

Hope it helps you.